# How does google web bots/crawlers work

Tags: asp.net, web, webserver, web-crawler, bots

I am looking into logs of my company website where we log client host name and ip address.
I noticed that every time I access the website, in addition to my ip and host name, There are other host names and ip address (baiduspider,googlebot etc.) logged that coincide with same time as my access.

How can they also access website, at the same time as my website access. Do they just monitor the traffic and follow with a copy request, when there is genuine user website access?

Are the crawlers and bots good or bad for the website? Don't they cost bandwidth for the website provider.

Comment: Hint: there is no such thing as magic.